# How can I call a javascript function and pass into it a row's object?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$('#dataTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', clickHandler);
```

Here's the first few lines of my gridClickHander

```
function gridClickHandler(event) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function () {
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $(this).addClass('row_selected');
    var rk = $(this).attr('data-rk');
    var pk = $(this).attr('data-pk');
```

This code now works very well.

Next I would like to do the same thing as the click event on a row but by using javascript/jQuery code calling the gridClickHandler. For example on a row with an id="row_25".  Is there a way I can do this? Sorry but again I am confused abut how to deal with the $(this).

Here's my code:

```
  if (obj.entity == "City") {
                var html = obj.$form.find("#select-topic").html();
                var indx = obj.$form.find("#select-topic").index()
                $("#input_TempRowKey_" + obj.rownum).html(html);
                $("#input_TempRowKey_" + obj.rownum).eq(indx).attr('selected', 'selected');
                var title = obj.$form.find("#Title").val();
                $("#input_Title_" + obj.rownum).val(title);
                $("tr#row_" + obj.rownum).attr("data-rk", json.rowKey);
                // here I need to do the same as though a user just clicked on rownum
            }
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is... you are already binding the click event handler with jQuery. Or do you want to bind the handler to a specific row?

Comment: I have other code that I will execute and once it's finished I need to go back and I will need to execute the gridClickHandler again. However not by clicking. I want to do this from my other code and pass it the information on the row. The other code knows the number of the row.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem? Are you saying you want to trigger gridClickHandler event from your other code? Have you looked into trigger() function in jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `this` explicitly by using [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
gridClickHandler.call(referenceToDOMElement);
// example: gridClickHandler.call($('#row_25').get(0));
```

Note that the event handler expects `this` to be a DOM element, and not a jQuery object. Also, if your handler would make use of the event object (`event`) calling the function like this would of course not work.

The above way lets you execute the handler for *any* DOM element. But since you want to execute the handler for a row, you can simulate a click on a specific row:

```
$('#row_24').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. I will check it now.